# Spring data duplicate key value

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a table in postgresql with unique constraint and after insert i can get the error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`. How best way to skip this error (for example, ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING) using spring data?

Comment: Can you share the way you generate id?

Comment: this problem is not related to id, another field msut be unique.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Have the row inserted by undermining the constraint (impossible) or have java not throw an exception and continue with the method?

Comment: I can just check if there is such a value in the database and if there is not, then insert it, but can I do it in 1 request?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to forget the row in case of conflict, just use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT (field) DO NOTHING`.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the `DataIntegrityViolationException` exception and handle it the way you want e.g.

```
try {
    repository.save(myEntity);
} catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    System.out.println("Entity already exists. Skipping ...");
}
```

Comment: If you use dataIntegrityViolationexception that would lead to suppressing other db exceptions as well and not just duplicatekey exception